# Application Initializer vs Application Instance Initializer

Tags: ember.js

I can't seem to figure out the difference between the two. The only difference I could see from the example is if somehow two instances of the application were running? How is that even possible?

Would someone be able to explain the difference between the two, and maybe with an example? I can't seem to wrap my head around the documentation: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/applications/initializers/

As for what I'm doing. I'm attempting to create a NotificationFactory so anyservice/util/component can create a defined Notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Application initializers are run as your application boots, and
>   provide the primary means to configure dependency injections in your
>   application.
>
> Application instance initializers are run as an application instance
>   is loaded. They provide a way to configure the initial state of your
>   application, as well as to set up dependency injections that are local
>   to the application instance (e.g. A/B testing configurations).

And read more at http://emberjs.com/deprecations/instance-initializers/

For your purposes it's better use application initializer thus it's callback got instance of  `Ember.Application` ( not `Ember.ApplicationInstance` ) so you can use http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html method to register your components/services/dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is it possible you can give an example of when you would use each one?

Comment: Is the main difference between the two just if I want something created each time an instance of the application is created, or when the application is first booted? Also its titled Deprecate Instance Initializers, but they said there is a new API for new Application Instance Initializers. So are they getting rid of them or not?